# 'find' some text including before and after lines

Tags: linux

I can find which files containing something.

`find /directory -name "*.log" | xargs grep "something"`

Problem is, it displays only one line and I need to see before and after lines.

It seems there's no option like I need : http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm

Or suggest me other way.

I download a log file on my PC and its size is 1.2GB. My `editplus` can't open it.

Comment: There are indeed [`grep` options](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Context-Line-Control) to control context.

Comment: Very thank you. I didn't know `grep` has options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do exactly what you are doing, but add the `-A and -B` options to grep. E.g:

```
find /directory -name "*.log" | xargs grep -A #above -B #below "something"
```

Replace `#above` with the number of lines above the match you would like, and similarly replace `#below` with a number for the lines you would like to see below the match.

Comment: Or if the the same number of lines before and after is wanted, then use the `-C` option.

Comment: Correct you are Sir. But it was a guess whether he wanted the same number above or below, so I just opted for the -A and -B. That way if he wanted a different number, we covered the worst case.

Comment: More than happy to help. Don't forget @JoachimPileborg suggestion as well. If you want the same number of lines above/below, you can use the `-C` option as well.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Yes, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep -C like this assuming you want to print lines after and before matched line.

```
grep -C 1 "something" filename.log
```

Comment: replace 1 with number of lines you want before and after matched line